# Why did Dr Zakir Naik say "Memory is washed off"?

Tags: tafseer, sunni, surat-al-ahzab

In this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQ7HiY49P3w&feature=youtu.be&t=7m54s

Dr Zakir Naik says that in the quran it says that:

> http://quran.com/33/72
>
> We did indeed offer the Trust to the Heavens
>   and the Earth and the Mountains; but they refused to undertake it,
>   being afraid thereof: but man undertook it;- He was indeed unjust and
>   foolish;-

However, Dr Zakir Naik then goes on to say that this question (that all humans were asked) was washed off from our memories, so we can perform the worldly test properly.

Dr Zakir Naik does not make it clear where it says that all human memory of this question has been washed off.  Anyone know where it says that once Allah asked all humans this question, their memory was washed off?

Comment: It could just be a claim of logic rather than of divine revelation, based on the fact that in general we mankind *don't* actually remember this happening.

Comment: Brother its a comment sense. Its in Quran that we chose to be Humans now if we don't remember it means our memory has been wipied out. Whats so complicated in it ?

Answer (score -2):

There isn't any evidence of this concept of "washed from your own memories" in Tafsir Ibn Kathir with the quoted verse. I also looked into Ma'ariful Quran this also also wasn't mentioned but there is an extensive explanation of this particular verse that has been insightful to say the lowest amount of.