# Where were we before birth?

Tags: creation

Where were we before birth?

When was our sprites created?

According the hadith below, if it is right, who was created with God first time?

There is a hadith with [Wikishia](http://id.wikishia.net/view/Hadis_Laulaka) reference.

How much time we were living before birth in this world?

What was our goal, before?

Why God depends assigning my ghost in specific time and position (How the time and position was chosen?)

### Hint

This question is not broad.

Sometimes we need ask questions that seems wide or broad, because of the questions content. perhaps they need publishing an article for answer!

My related question before is: ([Are we responsible ...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43878/are-we-responsible-for-our-behavior-in-the-world-god-or-servants))

Comment: Just because you add a hint and state: "this question is not broad", does not mean it isn't. As I can see from the content of the "question", it is too broad and unclear what exactly you are asking. Please try to be more specific, focus on one question.

Comment: @Kilise, I want what you advised. Please correct my question. Because I dont know how can made in more clear and focus with save the concept.

Comment: There is a unique major concept in my question. this need united story in answer. about our world before birth. Is it right I ask many separated questions for this matter? or is better I include related concept issues under a united question that we reached a comprehensive answer article?

Comment: In this case, I can split my question to this six parts as: (Your mean is I ask 6 times, this six separated questions against this one?) 1- Where were we before birth? - 2- When was our sprites created? 3- According the hadith below, if it is right, who was created with God first time? 4- How much time we were living before birth in this world? 5- What was our goal, before birth? 6- Why God depends assigning my ghost in specific time and position (How the time and position was chosen?)

Comment: You made me sad and angry in my [last question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/is-god-of-islam-righteous-justice) with this words. ;-(

Comment: What do you mean by :"Why God depends assigning **my ghost** in specific time and position (How the time and position was chosen?)" this is totally unclear to me!

Comment: Also as there's a certain mismatch between question title and content you should consider editing your question title to make it confirm the content.

Comment: We have Ghost (spirit) and body. Our body was birthed a day and in a position in this word. But our spirit was existed before we birth. Our spirits for birth, needs a time and position for done.

Comment: The spirit AFAIK  or understand was blown inside us while we were in our mothers womb. I still don't understand why you use the verb "to depend" in that expression!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hadith mentioned in the link ("Laulaka") which alleges that the universe was created because of Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) is not authentic or in line with the teaching of the Qur'an. Allah (ﷻ) told us why we were created; it was to worship Allah (ﷻ). That is the whole reason anything and anyone was created. Period. Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) was just someone who was created along with the rest of humanity but excelled above everyone due to his love of Allah (ﷻ), loyalty, commitment, good heart and righteousness.

(Note: Whoever does believe that the hadith is authentic would then by default have to believe that there was another realm in which people 'proved' themselves.. thus why the universe would be created for a particular person. This is why you are in this confusion and asking this question. But the premise is wrong so this line of thinking should not be taken further. *This* Dunya is the realm of being tested and proving yourself to Allah (ﷻ)).

With the above in mind, acknowledging that Allah (ﷻ) created the Universe as He Willed, we come to the question of what happened *before* this Dunya? Were we around in any way? - The answer is yes. Allah (ﷻ) told us about it on one instance in the Qur'an, when He extracted all souls of everyone who would be born later in the Dunya and we all equally testified that Allah is God.

> And [mention] when your Lord took from the children of Adam - from their loins - their descendants and made them testify of themselves, [saying to them], "Am I not your Lord?" They said, "Yes, we have testified." [This] - lest you should say on the day of Resurrection, "Indeed, we were of this unaware." - Qur'an 7:172.

^ That was the "Day of the Covenant".

As for the question of the "time frame"/timeline on everything that happened, very limited knowledge has been given. So nothing can be said for certain if there is nothing in the texts.

Comment: I disagree to some extent the hadith or ahadith says/say nothing about a life  before birth so taking it as an evidence for such a premise is already a mistake. Note that there are only a few scholars whom disagree with the meaning of the version of last hadith which you declared as not authentic! Based on logic the first two sound weird enough and can't be accepted!

Comment: Feel free to disagree but truth be told, the mistake is in your approach of dismissing any Qur’an verse which isn’t further expounded upon by hadith. This is an incorrect approach. Further, you are wrong even in that claim because there **are** hadith which further support the concept of souls existing before birth.. such as the hadith on souls being like conscripted soldiers. P.S - I didn’t say there was “life before birth”; I said our souls were around, which is verbatim proven from the Qur’an verse.

Comment: The correct view isn’t established by how many scholars accept it, but rather by the proofs in support of their views. I’ve explained the lack of logic in believing that the universe was created for a human which defies both the Qur’an verse and common sense. That hadith is like most hadith which exaggerate over the Prophet.

Comment: I haven't found any proof for an opposite view so far. Only a statement on whom disagrees the majority view and it is an unknown author to me.

Comment: However I now remember one question saying that our memory has been washed off which might be related https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/why-did-dr-zakir-naik-say-memory-is-washed-off

Comment: @Medi1Saif this [comment](http://www.islamicity.org/Quransearch/shownote.asp?chap=7&note=139) of the verse by Muhammed Asad might be relevant.